# Comment traduire "center embedding" en français?

Tags: traduction, anglais, linguistique

Je lisais tantôt un article Wikipedia de linguistique et je suis tombé sur le concept de "center embedding".

> In linguistics, center embedding is the process of embedding a phrase in the middle of another phrase of the same type. --- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_embedding)

Exemple. Un homme qu'une femme (qu'un enfant connait) aime.

Comment traduire cela en français? "Encastrement" n'est pas très joli, "insertion" un peu vague?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Il s'agirait d'un *enchâssement* (d'après le paragraphe "LING." de l'entrée correspondante de TLFi).

[image]

https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ench%C3%A2ssement.

Comment: Bien vu! Merci Frank

Comment: On enchâsse un objet [incise>], pas une phrase,[<incise] sauf tournure précieuse de style. C'est une *incise* https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/incise limitée par des *virgules* [incise>], qui permettent la lisibilité de la phrase,[<incise] et non par les parenthèses de l'exemple, traduction mot à mot maladroite de la question. Un homme qu'une femme, connue d'un enfant, aime ; ce n'est pas une tournure de phrase usuelle.

Comment: @Personne votre traduction ne convient pas pour illustrer le concept, puisque "connue d'un enfant" n'est pas consitutée de deux parties, entre lesquelles on pourrait enchasser une phrase du même type

Comment: @John …  Un homme, qu'une femme, qui est connue d'un enfant, qui a un chat, qui à vu l'homme, qui a vu l'ours, aime.  Peu lisible… c'est possible comme exercice de l'https://www.oulipo.net/ .